# What has happend, if my Ubuntu 19.04 freezes (including mouse)?

Tags: ssh, freeze

I'm running on AMD system, with a native Ubuntu 19.04.
When the freeze happened I tried to login via ssh. There was no chance to establish the connection. After restart, the ssh worked again.
However, the smb-service was up and running.

The freeze has happened out of the void just using mail client or any other office product.

Has someone experienced the same behaviour?

Comment: Your system did not react on ssh, but you had a samba server what worked?

Comment: I too find it hard to believe the system is frozen if samba is running, so it sounds more to me like desktop was frozen, ssh maybe wasn't running as a server maybe - do magic sysreq keyboard requests work?  Does the kernel respond to them?

Comment: tty session is the best test I know of in this case. also will allow you to shut down freezing app and regain control.

Comment: It was not possible to switch to the command line. [ctrl]+[alt]+[FN] | N€1..7 was not possible. No reaction. Still frozen screen. What are magic sysreqests?

Comment: ssh: I've rebooted the system and could log on to it with the same ssh command line from my second computer. Chances are high that ssh was running the first time too.